# Why is the Confederacy frequently depicted as heroic in film and literature?

Tags: literature, confederacy, movies

I was watching a remastered video from The Rebel and it occurs to me that often, if not the majority of the time, it is the Confederacy before, during and after the war which is shown in a sort of idealized/heroic way. Gone With the Wind was a very successful film in which again the South is treated fairly sympathetically. There are many other examples whereas I can't think of too many films in which the Union is shown in a positive light.

It is not like Hollywood was dominated by people with roots in the South -- maybe D. W. Griffith is the one example of a major director/producer from a Southern state.

Is it simply that the South, having lost after a long but doomed struggle, is better suited to be shown sympathetically? Or is there some other reason for this treatment of the Confederacy in art?

Comment: You should do some basic research about the "Lost cause of the Confederacy" [(at the very minimum, Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Cause_of_the_Confederacy) and try to ask a more concise question.

Comment: @SJuan76: That article is actually pretty helpful, would not have thought to search for "lost cause of the confederacy." this may end up answering my question.